# to fetch array key and compare wih a key in a different array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a table that stores subjects offered and a table that stores the results scored by the students in an exam, in displaying the results using a view table, I want the system to display a (-) where a student does not take that subject and a score where he is taking the subject.

The sample array of the subjects stored is:

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 101 [subName] => English )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 102 [subName] => Kiswahili )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 121 [subName] => Mathematics )
[3] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 231 [subName] => Biology )
[4] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 232 [subName] => Physics )
[5] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 233 [subName] => Chemistry )
[6] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 311 [subName] => History )
[7] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 312 [subName] => Geography )
[8] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 313 [subName] => CRE )
[9] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 443 [subName] => Agriculture )
[10] => stdClass Object ( [subCode] => 565 [subName] => Business Studies ) )
```

---

The array that contains results of the student to display is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 101 [score] => 78 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 102 [score] => 80 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 121 [score] => 70 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 231 [score] => 76 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 233 [score] => 76 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 311 [score] => 85 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 313 [score] => 90 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 2129 [subCode] => 565 [score] => 80 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 101 [score] => 60 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 102 [score] => 70 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 121 [score] => 85 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 231 [score] => 80 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 232 [score] => 80 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 233 [score] => 80 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 312 [score] => 95 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [admNo] => 4093 [subCode] => 565 [score] => 86 ) )
```

---

I need a solution where the view displays a (-) where the subcode in the subjects array is not found in the results array.

Comment: foreach($subjects as $subject) {
                    $code = $subject->subCode;
                    foreach ($subjectresults as $subresult) {

                        $subCode = $subresult->subCode;

                        if (!$code) {
                            echo "<td>";
                            echo $res = $subresult->score;
                            echo "</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>";
                            echo "-";
                            echo "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$subjects = Array (
array ( 'subCode' => 101, 'subName' => 'English' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 102, 'subName' => 'Kiswahili' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 121, 'subName' => 'Mathematics' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 231, 'subName' => 'Biology' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 232, 'subName' => 'Physics' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 233, 'subName' => 'Chemistry' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 311, 'subName' => 'History' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 312, 'subName' => 'Geography' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 313, 'subName' => 'CRE' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 443, 'subName' => 'Agriculture' ),
array ( 'subCode' => 565, 'subName' => 'Business Studies' ) 
) ;



$scores = Array ( '0' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 101, 'score' => 78 ), '1' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 102, 'score' => 80 ), '2' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 121, 'score' => 70 ), '3' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 231, 'score' => 76 ), '4' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 233, 'score' => 76 ), '5' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 311, 'score' => 85 ), '6' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 313, 'score' => 90 ), '7' => array ( 'admNo' => 2129, 'subCode' => 565, 'score' => 80 ), '8' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 101, 'score' => 60 ), '9' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 102, 'score' => 70 ), '10' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 121, 'score' => 85 ), '11' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 231, 'score' => 80 ), '12' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 232, 'score' => 80 ), '13' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 233, 'score' => 80 ), '14' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 312, 'score' => 95 )/*, '15' => array ( 'admNo' => 4093, 'subCode' => 565, 'score' => 86 )*/);

$students =  array(2129,4093);
print_r($students);

function took_test($scores,$admNo, $subj){
    $r = FALSE;
    foreach($scores as $score){
        if($score['subCode'] == $subj && $score['admNo'] == $admNo){
            $r =  "<td>".$score['score']."</td>";
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Student AdmNo</td>
<?php
foreach($subjects as $subj){
    echo "<td>".$subj['subName']."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($students as $s){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$s."</td>";
    foreach($subjects as $subj){
        if(!took_test($scores,$s,$subj['subCode'])){
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            }else{
            echo took_test($scores,$s,$subj['subCode']);
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>

<pre><?php
print_r($subjects);

print_r($scores);
?></pre>
```

Please take time to optimize this codes

Answer (score 0):

Combine both array and sort according to subcode, then the elements which are only passed once in the final array is what you are looking for.

You can use `comparable` or `comparator` to sort according to one instance in of your array if you are using java.

Comment: am using php codeigniter framework and i dont understand how i can loop through the two arrays comparing

Comment: you dont have to loop, tru two arrays, i dont have any knowledge on php, but in java, i can do that combine both array and you will have new array now. sort it according to subCode, i dont know how you will do it in php. when you sort it you will have the following: `arr[0]=101; arr[1]=101; arr[2]=102; arr[3]=102;...` As you see, the   common elements will come, one after the other

Comment: that would too work well if i can get an array function to combine the two arrays.

Comment: you should learn how to use google. This is basic array operation. `http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php`. Find something like that, but it should combine and protect ascending order while sorting, this is not supposed to be hard problem